# How to Share both image and text through whatsapp android programatically

Tags: android, android-studio, whatsapp

I need to share both an image and some text via WhatsApp, using an Intent on Android.

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(Filepath);
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My sample image text");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(imageUrl));
shareIntent.setType("image/png");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

try {
    startActivity(shareIntent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    ToastHelper.MakeShortText("Kindly install whatsapp first");
}
```

I’m using the code above, but it throws a 'File format not supported' error while sharing.

Comment: Most likely, WhatsApp lacks the right to access your stream. `Uri.parse(imageUrl)` seems like an unlikely way to get a valid `Uri` for sharing. What is the value of `imageUrl`?

Comment: https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/1900x800 .getting sharing failed,please try again. If i use url has jpg/png then it says File format not supported. Can you please tell me what format to use here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
  public static void shareOnWhatsapp(Context context, String str) {
    Uri parse = Uri.parse(str);
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("android.intent.action.SEND");
    intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    String stringBuilder = context.getResources().getString(R.string.play_more_app) +
            context.getPackageName();
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", stringBuilder);
    intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", parse);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.addFlags(1);
    try {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception unused) {
        setToast(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.whatsapp_not_installed));
    }
}
```

I used this function to share images it's working I hope it's work you too.

**Edit**

1. Add this dependency for converting URL to bitmap

   ```
       implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2'
   ```
2. Use this function to get Image URI to share

   ```
       private Uri getImageURI(Bitmap image) {
       File imagesFolder = new File(getCacheDir(), "images");
       Uri uri = null;
       try {
           imagesFolder.mkdirs();
           File file = new File(imagesFolder, "shared_image.png");

           FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
           image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
           stream.flush();
           stream.close();
           uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName() + ".provider", file);

       } catch (IOException e) {
           Log.d("TAG", "IOException while trying to write file for sharing: " + e.getMessage());
       }
       return uri;
   }
   ```
3. Use this function for share Image on WhatsApp

   ```
       public static void shareOnWhatsapp(Context context, Uri uri) {
       Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.setAction("android.intent.action.SEND");
       intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
       String stringBuilder = "Your String Or Message" +
               context.getPackageName();
       intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.TEXT", stringBuilder);
       intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.STREAM", uri);
       intent.setType("image/*");
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
       try {
           context.startActivity(intent);
       } catch (Exception unused) {
           Toast.makeText(context, "whatsapp not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Uses like this

   ```
           findViewById(R.id.btnShare).setOnClickListener(v -> {
           Glide.with(this).asBitmap().load( /*Your URL*/ "https://drinkprime.in/images/smart_water_purifier.jpg").into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
               @Override
               public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                   Bitmap bitmap = resource;
                   shareOnWhatsapp(MainActivity.this, getImageURI(bitmap));
               }

               @Override
               public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
               }
           });
       });
   ```

It's Working now completely

Comment: Hi thanks for the update but it is not working for me. No idea whether it is issue with the format of the imageurl or something else breaking.

Comment: can you check in logcat which URL you getting?

Comment: Okay, You need to convert this image URL into bitmap and then share the bitmap

Comment: @lakshmi Check the new code above it's working now

Comment: @jcredking your startActivity method should be like this activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"));